# Uniform and Compact Open Topology on spaces of maps from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

First, we define a metric. Let $$d^\infty(f,g) = \sup \{\rho(f(x),g(x))| x \in X\}$$ for some topological space $X$. Now let $Y$ be a metric space, and let $C_b(X,Y)$ denote the space of bounded continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$.

My question is to determine whether or not there are two spaces so that the topology generated by the metric is the compact-open topology on this space of bounded continuous functions.

So far, I have been able to show that if $X$ is compact, then the topology is the same. In light of this, it makes sense that we should only be looking at non-compact spaces. I have been trying to consider what happens in cases with spaces I am familiar with, like maps from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, but this has turned up nothing.

As a next approach, I wanted to produce two metrics on this space, and show they  do not produce equivalent topologies (while still looking at maps from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$). The idea was to write $\mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} [-n,n],$ and then use a metric defined by $$D_n (f,g) =\max\{ |f(x)-g(x)| : x \in [-n,n]\}$$ and then set $D(f,g)= \sum \frac{D_n (f,g)}{2^n (1+D_n (f,g))}$. This metric should be okay because all the maps in consideration are bounded, so it's easy to see this sum is well-defined.

The only reason I suspect something like this will work at all is because I have been told that this metric induces the compact-open topology, and so I thought it might be easier to compare two metrics and try to show that they do not produce equivalent topologies, by trying to violate the inequalities for equivalent metrics. For my purpose, this means it is enough to show that there do not exist numbers $k, K, k<K$ so that $kD(f,g) \leq d^\infty (f,g) \leq KD(f,g)$ for all $f,g$.

Intuitively, my (limited) experience with analysis makes me believe such functions can exist, but I need to find them.

Edit: I think I can, without loss of generality, just take one of the functions in each distance to be identically $0$, so that these distances simplify. In the first case, $d^\infty (f,0) = \sup \{\rho(f(x),0)) |x\in \mathbb{R} \}$, each $D_n = \max \{|f(x)|, x\in [-n,n]$ and so if we rename those values $\max_n f(x)$, then $D = \sum \frac{\max_n f}{2^n (1+ \max_n f)}$

Edit 2: After staring at these simplified metrics (formed by subtracting $g(x)$ from both functions and replacing $f(x)-g(x)$ with just $f(x)$ again, now I'm not sure eveything's right with this metric. Why don't constant maps show this? In one metric, constant maps with large image are actually *close* to 1, while in the other, they are just arbitrarily large. This makes me suspicious that something's wrong with the metric, but I can't see what.

Comment: Why did I get downvoted?

Comment: Doesn't
$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
0, &\text{ if } |x|\le n \\
x-\text{sgn}(x)n, &\text{ if } n\le|x|\le 2n\\
2\text{ sgn}(x)n, &\text{ if }2n\le|x|
\end{cases}
$$
converge compactly to $0$, but not uniformly.

Comment: @StefanHamcke I don't understand the relationship between the sequence and my question... Perhaps I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Aren't you asking whether the compact-open topology is different from the one induced by the sup-metric?

Comment: @StefanHamcke Yes, but I don't know what this has to do with sequences. The text I'm using just defines these topologies on spaces of functions, and doesn't talk about sequences. Can you talk me through what this sequence of functions shows?

Comment: Each topology on a space $X$ determines which sequences converge to which limit. If two topologies have the same convergent sequences, they need not be equal, but what we can say for sure, is that if some sequence converges to a limit with respect to one topology, but not with respect to the other, then the topologies are different. The sequence I gave converges compactly (that is, in the compact-open topology) to the constant map $0$, but not in the topology of uniform convergence (which is induced by the $\text{sup}$-metric).

Comment: @StefanHamcke I see! This is much more elegant way of putting it. I'm using Viro et al, and the book really shies away from sequences, and tries to do things with as much emphasis on the topology. Here is a really good example of when a sequential argument makes things truly simple, without masking the topology.

You should leave this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Note that the functions in my answer are a bit simpler than the ones I had put into my comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $Y$ is a metric space, the compact-open topology (which is also defined for a mere topological space $Y$) is the same as the topology of compact convergence, in which a sequence of maps $(f_n)_n$ converges to $f$ if and only if for each compact subset $K$ of $X$, the restrictions $f_n|_K$ converge uniformly to $f|_K$, i.e. with respect to the sup-metric restricted to $K$.

For $X=Y=\Bbb R$, the maps
$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
0, &\text{ if } x\le n \\
x-n, &\text{ if } n\le x\le n+1\\
1, &\text{ if }n+1\le x
\end{cases}
$$
for $n\in\Bbb N$, converge compactly to $f=0$ since on any bounded set they are eventually $0$. But they do not converge uniformly since $d^\infty(f_n,f)=1$ for any $n$.